# problems compiling the latest openssl v1.1.1m, linux

Tags: openssl

I've downloaded openssl-1.1.1m, and have gotten stuck compiling it on my GNU/Linux system.
./config shared
make

> (lots of stuff)
> ${LDCMD:-gcc} -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3   
> -o apps/openssl apps/asn1pars.o apps/ca.o apps/ciphers.o apps/cms.o apps/crl.o apps/crl2p7.o apps/dgst.o apps/dhparam.o apps/dsa.o apps/dsaparam.o apps/ec.o apps/ecparam.o apps/enc.o apps/engine.o apps/errstr.o apps/gendsa.o apps/genpkey.o apps/genrsa.o apps/nseq.o apps/ocsp.o apps/openssl.o apps/passwd.o apps/pkcs12.o apps/pkcs7.o apps/pkcs8.o apps/pkey.o apps/pkeyparam.o apps/pkeyutl.o apps/prime.o apps/rand.o apps/rehash.o apps/req.o apps/rsa.o apps/rsautl.o apps/s_client.o apps/s_server.o apps/s_time.o apps/sess_id.o apps/smime.o apps/speed.o apps/spkac.o apps/srp.o apps/storeutl.o apps/ts.o apps/verify.o apps/version.o apps/x509.o apps/libapps.a -lssl -lcrypto -L. -ldl -pthread 
> ./libcrypto.so: undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[1]: *** [apps/openssl] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory` /volume1/@config/openssl-1.1.1m'
> make: *** [all] Error 2

I've been reading around, and I moved -pthread to the end (as seen above), tried -lpthread, tried both, but those options provide the same result.  Anyone with suggestions?
One challenge, I'm stuck with gcc 3.4.6.